# Node.js ejs - How to convert a comma string into an array in the ejs templated and loop over

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I know I could convert the comma string into an array on the server side. Yet, is there also a way to convert a comma string into an array on the ejs template itself and then loop over the array and check if a certain value exists?

server.js

```
res.render('user', {
    page: 'User',
    menuId: 'user',
    groupID: '0,1,10702,10802'
});
```

user.html

```
<% for(var i=0; i < groupID.length; i++) { %>
  <% if (groupID[i] == '1') { %>
    <span>Admin</span>
  <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's totally possible:

```
<% groupID.split(",").forEach(element => { %>
    <% if (element === "1"){ %>
        <span>Admin</span>
    <% } %>
<% }); %>
```

Note: EJS Templates are still rendered on the Server-side! So it doesn't really matter if you just pass an Array from your server.js to EJS.